# Failed to bring data from JSON with PHP

Tags: php, json

I have searched so much before create this thread, and I can't solve my problem alone.

```
<?php
      $str = file_get_contents('private url');
      $json = json_decode($str);
      $json = json_decode($str, true);
      foreach($json as $x){
         $new_str = file_get_contents('private url/'.$x["anomaly_id"]);
         $new_json = json_decode($new_str);
         $new_json = json_decode($new_str, true);
         foreach($new_json as $new_x){
            echo  "<tr> <td data-title='Prefix'>".$new_x["prefix"]. "</td></tr>";
        }
      }
?>
```

So, I'm getting some values from a URL and looping it on another URL to take different results, but I'm getting some erros like:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'prefix
Undefined index: prefix
```

Json:

```
{
"status": "Open",
"prefix": "153.212.26.75/32",
"group": "TABLE",
"anomaly": "Error",
"direction": "Incoming",
"decoder": {
},
 "unit": "bits/s",
 "class": "Thresholds",
 "prefix_id": {
 "prefix": "153.212.36.0/22",
 "href": "/wanguard-api/v1/ip_zones/1/prefixes/1152"
}
```

Also, I can't give the URL, it's private, it's not mine.
I don't know how to solve this problem. Can you help me?

Comment: Your posted json string is invalid.   Please improve your question. To provide true/accurate data.  I am not trying to be bully on this page  -- this is just page clean up.  Future SO readers benefit most from clear questions and helpful/correct answers. Anything else will only contribute to confusion and page bloat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are "over iterating" because there is only one level in the array, drop the foreach loop and just access it on directly:

```
  $str = file_get_contents('private url');
  $json = json_decode($str, true);
  foreach($json as $x){
     $new_str = file_get_contents('private url/'.$x["anomaly_id"]);
     $new_json = json_decode($new_str, true);
     echo  "<tr> <td data-title='Prefix'>".$new_json["prefix"]. "</td></tr>";
  }
```

Comment: ...unless I am misunderstanding that you want all `prefix` elements, including `$new_json['prefix_id']['prefix']`.  What is the real/valid json value?  We are all left to make our own assumptions.

Comment: Thanks! Now it's working perfectly!

Comment: @Giuseppe Did you upvote Abid's answer?  It is not actually an answer, it is a comment that informs you that your posted json string is invalid.  Abid is requesting that you improve your question (which you should) but upvoting a non-answer/solution is rewarding inappropriate posting.

Comment: @Giuseppe Abid will be less likely to post his advice in the appropriate location while earning rep points on his answer.

Answer (score 1):

seems you are referiing to the wrong var  try accessing $new_x (and not $x2)

```
foreach($new_json as $new_x){
 echo  "<tr> <td data-title='Prefix'>".$new_x["prefix"]. "</td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed and the error is the same.

Comment: update your question and add a JSON file sample ..  so we can evaluate the possible content

Comment: (fyi, this is not a working solution, please remove)

Comment: Who had upvoted this incorrect answer?